# Show next file_input once first one has a value selected

Tags: javascript, css, forms, file-upload, upload

I'm trying to do a form with an option to upload an image or two at the bottom of the form.

So far the html form works fine and looks like this;

**HTML**

```
<form action="new.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    Affected Service<br><input type="text" name="affected" style="width:40vw;"><br><br>
    Summary<br><input type="text" name="title" style="width:40vw;"><br><br>
    Description<br><textarea name="description" style="width:40vw;" rows="8"></textarea><br><br>
    <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="1000000" />
    Choose a file to upload (max 2 - jpg or png only):<br>
    <input id="uploaded_file" name="uploaded_file" type="file" onchange="file2Function()" /><br>
    <input id="uploaded_file2" name="uploaded_file2" type="file" /><br>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button></form>
```

Now in order to look a bit better, I wanted the 2nd file input to only show once the 1st one has a value (i.e. the user has selected a file). So I put together the below javascript, which works in principle. However it doesn't actually do what I want it to because the 2nd file input field is shown by default when the page is first loaded, therefore making it obsolete.
If I set the css for "uploaded_file2" to "display:none;" then it hides it, but in turn the javascript can't make it display.

**JS**

```
      <script>
var file = document.getElementById("uploaded_file");
var target = document.getElementById("uploaded_file2");

function file2Function() {
  if(file.files.length > 0 ) {
    target.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    target.style.display = "none";
  }
}
</script>
```

**CSS**

```
          #uploaded_file2{
    display:none;
          }
```

Furthermore, while we are here .. if I want to make it 5 files, instead of just 2. Is there an easier way to use a single javascript function or would I be creating 4x functions? I ideally want to extend it to 5 files if I can do it in a simpler way!

Thanks all..

Comment: Code works fine for me: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/qvyz87wh/ Did you by any chance put the `<script>` above the `<form>` and not check the console?

Comment: How weird .. I have the css within `<style>` within `<head>` and the rest in `<body>` and I've double checked, the `<script>` is near the bottom of the page and definitely not in nor before `<form>`. Thanks for clarifying that much for me that it does work though! *scratches head*

Comment: So did you check the browser console? Any errors in there?

Comment: You legend. There was clearly something stupid I did in there that stopped it working. There was an error for some fancy stylesheet which I commented out but I'm not sure if that was it, but copying the code back in from scratch (where I posted above) worked just nicely so it's working as expected now, and like you showed me on jsfiddle. So thanks again Chris!!